# "Yield from" in Haskell Pipes

Tags: haskell, generator, coroutine, haskell-pipes

In [Haskell Pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes), suppose I am writing `f :: Producer a m ()` and I am inside a do block with respect to `m` (**Edit:** this doesn’t make sense; I want a producer do block). Inside this do block, I want to yield from `g :: Producer a m ()` before returning to my do block. How do I accomplish that?

In my particular case, `a = ()` and `m = State s`, and my producers are managing some branching behavior which only affects the state. `g` happens to yield only once, so in Python language, it's a context manager that changes some state, yields, then cleans up for itself. So in Python I could "yield from g" or use `@contextmanager` on `g` and enter a `with` block.

**Edit:** What I'm looking for is to write branches for a backtracking function, something like

```hask
do
 whenM accept_this_one (lift move_to_next)
 forM_ choices \i -> 
   when (notM (bad_choice i)) (lift (select i))
```

`g` is like `select i`, so think of `g` as `i_type -> Producer () m ()`.

`move_to_next` and `select` are both like context managers, cleaning up after themselves. So the state changes from `move_to_next` should last until (the end of the block? Here I'm confused. But certainly longer than the single line.) This should give something one can iterate over, and it manages the state for you.

In response to a question about how the state is affected, `f` should incorporate state changes from `g`, in the way it would in Python if we said `yield from g`, and `f` and `g` had access to common state.

**Edit2:** Here's a Python version of what I want:

```py
@contextmanager
def move_to_next():
    # do stuff
    yield
    # undo stuff
    return

@contextmanager
def selected(i):
    # do stuff
    yield
    # undo stuff
    return

if accept_this_one():
    cm = move_to_next()
else:
    cm = contextlib.nullcontext()
with cm:
    for i in choices:
        if not bad_choice(i):
            with selected(i):
                # Do stuff if you want
                yield
```

**Edit 3:** Maybe this?

```hask
select : i_type -> Prod () m ()
move_to_next : Prod () m ()
accept_this_one : m bool

do
 let x = ifM (lift accept_this_one)
           then move_to_next
           else yield
 x ~> \_ -> forM_ choices \i -> 
   when (notM (bad_choice i)) (select i)
```

Comment: How do you want `g`'s state changing to interact with `f`? In the simplest case, this is just `f = do { something ; g ; somethingElse }`, but that means `f` will incorporate the state changes `g` performs, and they'll be visible to `somethingElse`. Is that acceptable/desirable? Do you want it isolated further? There are options for all of these cases, but you need to describe what behavior you want.

Comment: @HTNW My mistake, assume I’m in the kind of do block you mention.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` (effectively, in this context) has the type `a -> Producer a m ()`. You cannot use it in the `do` block of a `m`, only the `do` block of a `Producer a m ()`. If you need to use a `State`, you need to `lift` it to `Producer` first:

```hs
f :: Producer s (State s ()) ()
f = do
      x <- lift get
      yield x
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this addresses part of my confusion.

Comment: Isn't it `f = lift get >>= yield`? I don't think `lift get` even has the same type.

Comment: @Carl - you are correct. the first statement outputs `x` on the Producer's downstream interface, while `lift get` makes it the Producer's return value. Edited my answer.